# Generating HTML <BASE> tag in JavaScript. Strange effects

Tags: javascript, html, css, radix

I am having some inconsistencies  regarding generating the HTML  BASE tag in javaScript.

I have a global script of which the relevant parts are below. Every page in my site points to this script relatively. Then in the head section I call the following: generateBase();.

This appears to work well. All my CSS Twitter bootstrap files appear to do their job, the page renders and I've had no complaints from users. Looking at the logs on our server, and the developer console in chrome the it would seem that all links to JavaScript or CSS files are incorrectly relatively addressed.

Below is my header which calls generateBase() in settings.js. Below this is the important bits of settings.js.

Whilst I do not want to give the actual URL away, a flavor of the problem is below. I am expecting http://somewebsite.com/~mysite/js/bootstrap.js as the address for the bootstrap.js file. Howeever chrome reports that it is looking for http://somewebsite.com/~mysite/subfolder/subdir/js/bootstrap.js  and gives a 403 even though the generateBase() call points to http://somewebsite.com/~mysite/. What I need is regardless of where each page of my site is located for them to be able to point to the  required CSS and Javascripts that app pages need. I want the ability move a page without having to update all the URLS inside it.

Below is the head:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/settings.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">generateBase();</script> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="css/bootstrapPurple.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/carousel-custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/pageStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/equalise.js"></script>
</head>
```

Settings.js Below:

```
var baseTestURL = "http://localhost/mySite/";//test local
var baseURL = "http://somewebsite.com/~mysite/";//live


function getBaseURL(){
   if(test)
        return baseTestURL;
   else
        return baseURL;      
}

function generateBase() {
    document.write('<base href="' + getBaseURL() + '" />');
}
```

PS I am aware of a similarly titled thread here ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211142/how-to-solve-a-problem-with-base-tag)). But the answer was not accepted, nor fully addressed the original question. Hence I ask this. Which is a more fuller explanation of the problem which may or may not be related.

Comment: How are they are incorrect? i.e. what's the resulting url that's causing trouble? I've never looked into issues with setting the base href dynamically, but this seems safer and more efficient to define server-side rather than executing client-side code every page request. You'll likely see errors for anyone/bots not using javascript.

Comment: Whilst I do not want to give the actual URL away, a flavor of the problem is below. I am expecting http://somewebsite.com/~mysite/js/bootstrap.js. I get http://somewebsite.com/~mysite/subfolder/subdir/js/bootstrap.js  even though the generateBase() call points to http://somewebsite.com/~mysite/

Comment: Your last script tag doesn't have a closing tag. Where is the variable test set? If your test site and live sites mirror each other and you are using relative addressing then there isn't any need to set the base tag.

Comment: @jeff thanks I have fixed that. That is just the remnant of some local code I wrote to test things out. I've removed it now.